# Adding boundary shadows to RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-drawable, radial-gradients

I have a horizontal `RecyclerView` that occupies a part of the entire screen and it's background is transparent. I have to depict the boundaries of the `RecyclerView` towards its ends by vertical lines that have a horizontal gradient and should taper off vertically towards both ends. The below image depicts what I have right now:

[image]

Basically I have shown the horizontal boundary of the recyclerview by drawing vertical views with a `5dp` width and backgrounds with horizontal gradients. I want these horizontal gradients to taper off vertically towards both the ends.

- Is there any inbuilt mechanism that does this for the `RecyclerView`
- If not, how can I taper off these vertically towards the ends?

**Edit 1**
I was able to set the fading edges using the property.

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
```

The problem is that I cannot change the tint for that. I want a greyish tint for the fading edges. I have tried to set it by mentioning `cacheColorHint` with grey color code but this seems to have no effect. This is the code for my recycler view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvTonics"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="10dp"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

And it generates layout like this:

[image]

What I want is the fading edges should have greyish tint. Possible?

Comment: @artkoenig Updated the question.

Comment: @duggu Updated the question.